# ¿como puedo mostrar un log en un JTextArea?

Tags: java, logger

Siento que mi problema tiene una solución simple, pero sin embargo no la encuentro.
Tengo un proyecto que cada determinado tiempo realiza una consulta a una tabla dentro de un BD, si cierta columna tiene como valor "0" muestra esa fila en una tabla, en caso de que no exista ninguna fila con cierta columna con valor "0" debo mostrar un log que diga "sin alertas de pánico" la cosa es que debo mostrarlo dentro de un JTextArea y simplemente no se como, ya que los log por lo general se imprimen en consola, dejo el pedazo de código donde tengo el log:

```
public class ConsultarBD {
Conexión c = new Conexión();

private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("AlertasBD.ConsultarBD");

public ArrayList<GT> Alertas_Panico() throws SQLException{
ArrayList<GT> list = new ArrayList<GT>();
Connection con = connect();

String sql = "SELECT * FROM alertas_panico WHERE reportado = 0";
try{
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
GT GT = new GT();
GT.setCentro(rs.getInt(2));
GT.setCaja(rs.getString(3));
GT.setFecha_hora(rs.getString(5));
GT.setCajero(rs.getString(6));
list.add(GT);
}
}catch(SQLException e){
System.out.println("log: " + e);
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}finally{
try{
c.closeCon();
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("ERROR AL CERRAR CONEXIÓN: " + e);
}
}

if(list.size()== 0){    //Si esta condición se cumple ejecuta la función ctrl() la cual muestra el log.
    ctrl();
}
return list;}

public void ctrl() throws SQLException{   
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Sin registros de pánico encontrados");
}

 }
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, solo soy un novato!

Adjunto foto de como va quedando:
[image: IMAGEN DE REFERENCIA]

Y adjunto foto del log en consola:
[image: log en consola]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos de un log son vacíos generalmente. Por lo que no se pueden agregar a un JTextArea.

Yo haría algo simple.

En el Main donde se encuentra JTextArea crearía una función publica estática y por parámetro pasaría un texto. Esto te puede dar una idea. Saludos.

En tu clase Main:

```
 public static void setTexto(String texto) {
    textArea.setText(texto);
 }
```

En la clase BD:

```
public void ctrl()  {
    Main.setTexto(logString("Sin registros de pánico encontrados", 
            "AlertasBD.ConsultarBD", 
            "info"));
}

private String logString(String mensaje, String contexto, String level) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .append(" ").append(contexto)
            .append(System.lineSeparator());
    switch (level) {
        case "info":
            sb.append("INFORMACION: ");
            break;
        case "error":
            sb.append("ERROR: ");
            break;
        case "warn":
            sb.append("ADVERTENCIA: ");
            break;
    }
    sb.append(mensaje);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, te agradezco que te hayas tomado la molestia.

Answer (score -1):

Pero no hay necesidad de que sea un log, lo único que tienes que hacer es mostrar ese mensaje en el JTextArea como si fuera cualquier texto.

Comment: Necesito que sea especificamente un log, por el tema de que el log muestra cierta información adicional al mensaje, así como se muestra en la imagen que adjunte.

Comment: Pero que información? No hay ninguna información en un log que no la puedas escribir tú directamente.

Comment: Voy a seguir tu consejo mejor.
gracias de antemano.